# Issue where is_null not working even when conditions are false

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below when $start_limit and $end_limit are FALSE then A should be run. Instead B is occurring. I've tested that both variables are FALSE with var_dump.

I am using is_null because $start_limit is occasionally set to 0 and I want a condition where 0 counts as TRUE.

```
if (is_null($start_limit) && is_null($end_limit)) { 
         A      

} else {
         B          

}
```

Any suggestions as to how to get A to run when both variables are FALSE would be very much appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Just use coercion-to-boolean. `!0` and `!false` both evaluate to `true`.

```
if (!$start_limit && !$end_limit) { 
    // A
} else {
    // B          
}
```

http://ideone.com/aBbWJ

Comment: Thank you, that did it! Only thing I don't get even after looking at the PHP docs is is_null didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use === instead of is_null. False is not null, but 0 !== false. The triple equality check is the type of exact matching you are looking for.

perhaps

```
if( false === $start_limit && !$end_limit ) {
 // there are no limits, set the course for the heart of the sun!
}
else {
  B
}
```